# getting a Firefox plugin to detect and mimic attempts to check for Apple Pay support

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, applepayjs

Now that Apple's credit card offering is out, I can get 2% cash back on purchases on the web made with Apple Pay. Unfortunately, my browser of choice is Firefox, which doesn't yet support Apple Pay.

I'd like to detect attempts to check for Apple Pay support, so I can alert myself in some way and switch over Safari to complete my purchase. Per [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/apple_pay_js_api/checking_for_apple_pay_availability), this check is performed via `window.ApplePaySession`.

So, I've attempted the following in an extension:

**`manifest.json`**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "applepay",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://*/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "applepay.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**`applepay.js`**

```js
window.ApplePaySession = {
    canMakePayments: function () {
        console.log('canMakePayments');
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    },
    canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard: function () {
        console.log('canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard');
        Promise.resolve(true);
    },
};
```

I'm able to `console.log(window)` in `applepay.js` and get the whole object, but my *changes* to the object don't appear to take effect - it's acting like `window` is read-only. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Firefox, content scripts (addon written in WebExtensions) don't share the same context as page scripts (website scripts).

In your content script, do something similar to this:

```
function notify(message) {
   console.log("do something");
}

exportFunction(notify, window, {defineAs:'notify'});
```

After, the page script will see that window.notify exists.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts